# Is it right concept if I used Async Await with react life cycles specially with ComponentDidMount for api calls?

Tags: reactjs

Is it right way to use **Async Await** with **Component Life Cycles** specially with **ComponentDidMount** for Api calls? 
I want to know about whether it have some cons are not in-terms of performance ?

Answer (score 2):

Not at all. This is a common React pattern for data fetching.

There are no cons in terms of performance as far as I know. Infact, this is how I usually do data fetching in my React components.

When I'm using `react-hooks` [DOC Link](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-intro.html), this is done inside `useEffect`, which is similar to the `componentDidMount` and `componentDidUpdate` methods.

**CodeSandBox:** https://codesandbox.io/s/polished-wood-0rr99

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

function mockAPI() {
  return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
    setTimeout(()=>resolve('bar'),1500);
  });
}


class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      propA: 'foo'
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.callMockAPI();
  }

  async callMockAPI() {
    const result = await mockAPI();
    console.log('Result: ' + result);
    this.setState({propA: result});
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div>{this.state.propA}</div>
    );
  }

}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 1):

I have used it before and it didn't have any significant performance cons on my project. It is okay to use Async/await on ComponentDidMount. I did something like

```
async componentDidMount() {
  const res = await fetch('url')
  const something = await res.json()
  this.setState({something})
}
```